# How to find the average value/sum of combinations with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, average

Let's say I have a set $\{1, 2, ...x\}$ and pick every distinct combination of length 3 (including repeated numbers) and create a new set by adding values equal to the product of the elements in each combination. For example, if x = 4 the new set would be:

$$\{1*1*1, \ 2*1*1, \ 2*1*2, \ 2*2*2,\ 3*1*1,\ ... \ , 4*4*3, \ 4*4*4\}$$

These combinations are unique (that is, no value in the new set is repeated).

My goal is to find the sum of these values in terms of $x$. I already know the size of the new set in terms of $x$ which is why I ask for the average value (unless finding the sum is easier without the average and size).

Hopefully my explanation of the set was clear but if needed I can elaborate more.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Isn't the sum just $(1+2+\cdots+x)^3?$

Comment: Well for example, for x = 2 the sum would be 1*1*1 + 2*1*1 + 2*2*1 + 2*2*2 = 15, but 3^3 = 27. I think that form would be if the elements were not distinct in the new set. Although that does give me an idea...

Comment: I thought you would be counting $1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot1$ etc. as well.  I guess you want to count the product of the same three numbers only once then.  Is that right?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I'll edit it so it's clearer on that.

Comment: I'm too sleepy to write an answer now, but you do this by starting with the expression I suggested at first, and isolating the parts with $1,2,$ or $3$ distinct factors.  If you haven't got it worked out by tomorrow, ping me and I'll write an answer.

Comment: Sure thing. It's 2am here so I may wait till morning to work on this more lol. But I'll ping you if I need a little more help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little different approach.  I will write $n$ instead of $x$ as the variable.  It's silly, but I can't get used to $x$ being an integer variable.

We seek to evaluate $T=T_1+T_2+T_3,$ where 
$$\begin{align}
T_3&=\sum_{i=1}^n{i^3}\\
T_2&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1\\j\ne i}^n{ij^2}\\
T_1&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=k+1}^n{ijk}
\end{align}$$
We will use the following well-known formulas:
$$\begin{align}
S_3&=\sum_{i=1}^n{i^3}={n^2(n+1)^2\over4}\\
S_2&=\sum_{i=1}^n{i^2}={n(n+1)(2n+1)\over6}\\
S_1&=\sum_{i=1}^n{i}={n(n+1)\over2}
\end{align}$$
Note first that $$T_3=S_3\tag{1}$$ 
Then 
$T_2=(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)(1+2+\cdots+n)-(1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3).$  That is,
$$T_2=S_2S_1-S_3\tag{2}$$
To compute $T_1,$ note that in the expression $(1+2+3+\cdots+n)^3,$ each term of $T_3$ occurs once, each term of $T_2$ occurs $3$ times, and each term of $T_1$ occurs $6$ times so that 
$$\begin{align}
S_1^3 &= T_3+3T_2+6T_1\\
T_1&={S_1^3-T_3-3T_2\over6}=\\
&={S_1^3-S_3-3S_2S_1+3S_3\over6}=\\
&={S_1^3-3S_2S_1+2S_3\over6}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
using $(1)$ and $(2)$.
Now, using $(1),(2),\text{ and }(3),$ we get $$T={S_1^3+3S_2S_1+2S_3\over6},$$ and substituting the formulas for $S_1,S_2,S_3$ and slogging through the algebra gives $$T=\boxed{{n^2(n+1)^2(n+2)(n+3)\over48}={n+1\choose2}{n+3\choose4}}$$
Sanity check: $n=2$ gives ${3\choose2}{5\choose4}=3\cdot5=15,$ in agreement with your calculation.

Comment: I'm in awe yet again at the genius of some of the users here. This is practically the exact type of answer I was looking for. Thank you so much! I apologize that you had to go through all that algebra though...

Comment: @Gizmo Glad to help.  No apology needed.  This is not genius by any means, but well-known technique.

Answer (score 0):

Using saulspatz's advice, I found that the sum of the terms in the new set of size $x$ is equivalent to:

$$(1 +  \cdots + x)^3 - (1 + \cdots + x)(2 + 3(1+2) + \cdots + x(1 + \cdots + x))$$ $$= 
\left( \sum_{i=0}^xi \right) *\left[ \left( \sum_{i=0}^xi \right)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^x i *\left(\sum_{j=0}^i j    \right)   \right]$$

[image]

While I offer my gratitude to saulspatz for his/her help I do wonder if this could be expressed more simply.

Edit: I included a picture of an example of $x = 4$ to show this equivalency, where $S_A$ is the sum of the terms in the new set (what we are trying to find).

Comment: I don't see how you arrived at this formula.  Please fill in the reasoning.  The formula can certainly be simplified, but I'd like to be sure it's correct before I show you how to do that.

Comment: Don't worry I compared it with the original to make sure it's equivalent. Essentially I multiplied out $(1 + \cdots + x)^3$ and isolated the terms that show up in the original sum/new set. The rest of the terms from $(1 + \cdots + x)^3$ can be arranged in the form $(1 + \cdots + x) (1*0 + 2*1 + 3*(1 + 2) + \cdots + x(1 + \cdots + x))$.